# What does this code does ? There are so many weird things

Tags: c

```
int n_b ( char *addr , int i ) {
    char char_in_chain = addr [ i / 8 ] ;
    return char_in_chain >> i%8 & 0x1;
}
```

Like what is that : " i%8 & Ox1" ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. `%` is the modulo operator and `&` is the bitwise `AND` operator. `0x1` is an integer constant in hexadecimal notation. This should be handled in the first chapters of any C text book.

Comment: And whenever you have to deal with operators you must take care about the precedence. See [Wiki: Operators in C and C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: Step 1: research what these various operators are used for. Step 2: research operator precedence in the expression, since the code is written without parenthesis. Step 3: try to make sense of the code. Hint: to access an individual byte number `i` in a bitfield/array of raw data bytes, `i/8` gives the byte number and `i%8` gives the bit number.

Comment: 0th question: what is `char_in_chain >> i%8 & 0x1`? Is it `(char_in_chain >> i%8) & 0x1` or `char_in_chain >> (i%8 & 0x1)`. I have no idea by heart. I could look it up ... but it's much more quick to have parenthesis in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Note that 0x1 is the hexadecimal notation for 1. Also note that :

`0x1 = 0x01 = 0x000001 = 0x0...01`

`i%8` means i modulo 8, ie the rest in the Euclidean division of i by 8.

`& 0x1` is a bitwise AND, it converts the number before to binary form then computes the bitwise operation. (it's already in binary but it's just so you understand)

Example : `0x1101 & 0x1001 = 0x1001`

Note that any number & 0x1 is either 0 or one.

Example: `0x11111111 & 0x00000001 is 0x1` and `0x11111110 & 0x00000001 is 0x0`

Essentially, it is testing the last bit on the number, which the bit determining parity.

Final edit:

I got the precedence wrong, thanks to the comments for pointing it out. Here is the real precedence.

First, we compute i%8.

The result could be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

Then, we shift the char by the result, which is maximum 7. That means the `i % 8` th bit is now the least significant bit.

Then, we check if the original `i % 8` bit is set (equals one) or not. If it is, return 1. Else, return 0.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the value of a specific bit in a `char` array as the integer 0 or 1.

`addr` is the pointer to the first `char`.

`i` is the index to the bit. 8 bits are commonly stored in a `char`.

First, the `char` at the correct offset is fetched:

```c
    char char_in_chain = addr [ i / 8 ] ;
```

`i / 8` divides `i` by 8, ignoring the remainder. For example, any value in the range from 24 to 31 gives 3 as the result.

This result is used as the index to the `char` in the array.

Next and finally, the bit is obtained and returned:

```c
    return char_in_chain >> i%8 & 0x1;
```

Let's just look at the expression `char_in_chain >> i%8 & 0x1`.

It is confusing, because it does not show which operation is done in what sequence. Therefore, I duplicate it with appropriate parentheses: `(char_in_chain >> (i % 8)) & 0x1`. The rules (operation precedence) are given by the C standard.

First, the remainder of the division of `i` by 8 is calculated. This is used to right-shift the obtained `char_in_chain`. Now the interesting bit is in the least significant bit. Finally, this bit is "masked" with the binary AND operator and the second operand `0x1`. BTW, there is no need to mark this constant as hex.

---

Example:

The array contains the bytes 0x5A, 0x23, and 0x42. The index of the bit to retrieve is 13.

`i` as given as argument is 13.

`i / 8` gives 13 / 8 = 1, remainder ignored.

`addr[1]` returns 0x23, which is stored in `char_in_chain`.

`i % 8` gives 5 (13 / 8 = 1, remainder 5).

0x23 is binary 0b00100011, and right-shifted by 5 gives 0b00000001.

0b00000001 ANDed with 0b00000001 gives 0b00000001.

The value returned is 1.

---

*Note: If more is not clear, feel free to comment.*

Answer (score 0):

What the various operators do is explained by any C book, so I won't address that here. To instead analyse the code step by step...

The function and types used:

- `int` as return type is an indication of the programmer being inexperienced at writing hardware-related code. We should always avoid signed types for such purposes. An experienced programmer would have used an unsigned type, like for example `uint8_t`. (Or in this specific case  maybe even `bool`, depending on what the data is supposed to represent.)
- `n_b` is a rubbish name, we should obviously never give an identifier such a nondescript name. `get_bit` or similar would have been a better name.
- `char*` is, again, an indication of the programmer being inexperienced. `char` is particularly problematic when dealing with raw data, since we can't even know if it is signed or unsigned, it depends on which compiler that is used. Had the raw data contained a value of `0x80` or larger and `char` was negative, we would have gotten a negative type. And then right shifting a negative value is also problematic, since that behavior too is compiler-specific.
- `char*` is proof of the programmer lacking the fundamental knowledge of *const correctness*. The function does not modify this parameter so it should have been `const` qualified. Good code would use `const uint8_t* addr`.
- `int i` is not really incorrect, the signedness doesn't really matter. But good programming practice would have used an unsigned type or even `size_t`.

With types unsloppified and corrected, the function might look like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t get_bit (const uint8_t* addr, size_t i ) {
    uint8_t char_in_chain = addr [ i / 8 ] ;
    return char_in_chain >> i%8 & 0x1;
}
```

---

This is still somewhat problematic, because the average C programmer might not remember the precedence of `>>` vs `%` vs `&` on top of their head. It happens to be `%` over `>>` over `&`, but lets write the code a bit more readable still by making precedence explicit: `(char_in_chain >> (i%8)) & 0x1`.

Then I would question if the local variable really adds anything to readability. Not really, we might as well write:

```
uint8_t get_bit (const uint8_t* addr, size_t i ) {
    return ((addr[i/8]) >> (i%8)) & 0x1;
}
```

---

As for what this code actually does: this happens to be a common design pattern for how to access a specific bit in a raw bit-field.

- Any bit-field in C may be accessed as an array of bytes.
- Bit number `n` in that bit-field, will be found at byte `n/8`.
- Inside that byte, the bit will be located at `n%8`.
- Bit masking in C is most readably done as `data & (1u << bit)`. Which can be obfuscated as somewhat equivalent but less readable `(data >> bit) & 1u`, where the masked bit ends up in the LSB.

For example lets assume we have 64 bits of raw data. Bits are always enumerated from 0 to 63 and bytes (just like any C array) from index 0. We want to access bit 33. Then 33/8 integer division = 4.

So `byte[4]`. Bit 33 will be found at 33%8 = 1. So we can obtain the value of bit 33 from ordinary bit masking `byte[33/8] & (1u << (bit%8))`. Or similarly, `(byte[33/8] >> (bit%8)) & 1u`

---

An alternative, more readable version of it all:

```
bool is_bit_set (const uint8_t* data, size_t bit)
{
  uint8_t byte = data [bit / 8u];
  size_t  mask = 1u << (bit % 8u);
  return (byte & mask) != 0u;  
}
```

(Strictly speaking we could as well do `return byte & mask;` since a boolean type is used, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.)